# getGroupIdLevel1() in Android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Android TelephonyManager class has the method getGroupIdLevel1(). However, this method is only implemented in API level 18 (Android 4.3).
My question is how can I get GID level 1 for devices with API level 16 (Android 4.1)?
I need it for a samsung smartphone, so a specific solution for samsung can also help me.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to this problem.
I fetched an instance of IccFileHandler and (using reflection) I sent APDU commands with the method loadEFTransparent(). For this I had to use Handler and I had to change the classes SIMFileHandler and UsimFileHandler to return the proper path for GID1 command (using smali).
This was a lot of change, but finally it works.